# Cannot use list as a function parameter in Python

Tags: python, list, function, parameters

I have a function like this. For *args I want to use a list of different Excel tables.

```
def my_function(*args):
    for x in args:
        # some code
```

I use this to get the full paths to the tables and make a list of them. There are only tables in the folder I want to use.

```
cust_tables = os.listdir(r"my_folder")
cust_path = [r"my_folder" + "\\" + x for x in cust_tables]
```

This creates a list like this:

```
['C:\\some\\path\\to\\my\\table_1.xlsx', 'C:\\some\\path\\to\\my\\table_2.xlsx']
```

When I try to call the function `my_function(cust_path)`, I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\my.name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
    st = os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list
```

I can call the function when using `my_function(cust_path[0],cust_path[1])`.

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

You need to *unpack* the list elements when passing as arguments. You can use the splat (`*`) operator:

```
my_function(*cust_path)
```

otherwise, when you do `my_function(cust_path)`, it is passing the whole list as argument; so, `args` will be a one element tuple containing the list i.e. `args` will be `([<cust_path_elements ...>],)`.

Comment: Thank you! I have to admit it was a rather dumb question forgetting about unpacking.